# CUDA - int from device get not updated while copying it to host

Tags: pointers, cuda

i'm pretty new in CUDA (and in C also..), I'm trying to use the `int shared` as a flag to stop all threads devices when `finish` is set, but when I copy it back to host it never gets updated, I can do it with `char *` but it doesn't work while using a simple int

minimal code example:

```c
__global__ void bingo(int * finish){

    __shared__ int shared;

    if(threadIdx.x == 5){
        printf("\nassign to finish %d",threadIdx.x);
        shared = threadIdx.x;
        finish = (int*) threadIdx.x;
        printf("GPU says: %d\n",*finish);
        return;
    }
    __syncthreads();
    if(shared != NULL){
        printf("\nreturn from thread: %d", threadIdx.x);
        return;
    }
}

int main() {

    int* threadBingo;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&threadBingo, sizeof( int));

    bingo<<<1,10>>>(threadBingo );
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    int* threadWhoMadeBingo = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    
    cudaMemcpy(threadWhoMadeBingo, threadBingo, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    printf("\n thread who made bingo %d\n", *threadWhoMadeBingo);


    cudaDeviceReset();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    
    return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
assign to finish 5
GPU says: 5
return from thread: 0
return from thread: 1
return from thread: 2
return from thread: 3
return from thread: 4
return from thread: 6
return from thread: 7
return from thread: 8
return from thread: 9
 thread who made bingo 0
```

As you can see, the last line should be **5** not **0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found it:

line `finish = (int*) threadIdx.x;` should be -> `*finish = threadIdx.x;`.

I'll acept this answer in two days.